# Create an "H" from smaller "H"s

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, fractal

## Challenge

Create a function or program that, when given an integer `size`, does the following:

If `size` is equal to 1, output

```
H H
HHH
H H
```

If `size` is greater than 1, output

```
X X
XXX
X X
```

where `X` is the output of the program/function for `size - 1`

(If you prefer, you may have the base case correspond to `0`, so long as you specify in your answer)

Any of the following output formats are acceptable, whichever is more convenient for you:

- A string of the required structure with any two distinct characters corresponding to `H` and `space`
- A two-dimensional array with the required structure, with any two distinct values corresponding to `H` and `space`
- An array/list of strings, with one line of the output in each string, with any two distinct values corresponding to `H` and `space`

Leading spaces are allowed, as long as there is a constant amount of leading spaces on each line. The two distinct output characters can be dependent on anything you choose, as long as they are different.

Specify what output format your code is returning.

## Test Cases

`1`

```
H H
HHH
H H
```

`2`

```
H H   H H
HHH   HHH
H H   H H
H HH HH H
HHHHHHHHH
H HH HH H
H H   H H
HHH   HHH
H H   H H
```

`3`

```
H H   H H         H H   H H
HHH   HHH         HHH   HHH
H H   H H         H H   H H
H HH HH H         H HH HH H
HHHHHHHHH         HHHHHHHHH
H HH HH H         H HH HH H
H H   H H         H H   H H
HHH   HHH         HHH   HHH
H H   H H         H H   H H
H H   H HH H   H HH H   H H
HHH   HHHHHH   HHHHHH   HHH
H H   H HH H   H HH H   H H
H HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH H
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
H HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH H
H H   H HH H   H HH H   H H
HHH   HHHHHH   HHHHHH   HHH
H H   H HH H   H HH H   H H
H H   H H         H H   H H
HHH   HHH         HHH   HHH
H H   H H         H H   H H
H HH HH H         H HH HH H
HHHHHHHHH         HHHHHHHHH
H HH HH H         H HH HH H
H H   H H         H H   H H
HHH   HHH         HHH   HHH
H H   H H         H H   H H
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest byte count for each language wins!

Comment: Perfect for Charcoal probably... lol. Also welcome to PPCG! :D

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Nice first challenge!

Comment: May we use 0 based sizes?

Comment: @Adám that is acceptable

Comment: Forgot to check your acceptable outputs before I submitted, but would an array of strings be acceptable instead of a two-dimensional array? This is for languages where a string is not formally an array of characters, but its own data structure.

Comment: @ValueInk That's fine

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54453/generate-fractals-from-bit-patterns-in-ascii/)

Comment: Can I print the desired output instead of returning it? Can I give a program that instead of a function?

Comment: Are leading spaces (or whatever the chosen background character is) allowed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ABAA/ABBB: Generate this recursive 2D pattern](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/155305/41024)

Comment: @LuisMendo apologies, there are no restrictions on the two output characters so long as they are different. You can have them depend on whatever you want.

Comment: @Titus that's fine

Comment: @TonHospel Leading/trailing spaces are allowed so long as they are consistent across all lines (so the structure of the H remains)

Comment: I'd call this a "Sierpinski H"

Comment: I made a dot plot, but I don't think that qualifies: https://repl.it/repls/ShockedAgitatedKeygenerator

Comment: I just found a piece of paper from 2008 where I did exactly this! I was 8 at that time and very interested in fractals (meaning: even more than now). It's the fourth iteration. Photo: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ww7_i2phDWGwUNUZCte0Nr4YrKz_Mlxg

Comment: Apparently a I can't do Math. I was 12 in 2008, not 8. +2, not -2.

Answer (score 29):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 46 bytes

```
Nest[ArrayFlatten@{r={#,0,#},{#,#,#},r}&,1,#]&
```

Returns a 2d array of `0`s and `1`s.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixCoAgEADQXzkUmi4omouCaIx2cThCKSiD65YQv91qevBOks2dJPtK2UMLeXa3mIGZnukgERf6yG3UWKFO@Kl/ORVYo7ZFHi@z8B7EBAQFZQcKwZtgLUL8qkk2vw)

[image: Nest[ArrayFlatten@{r={#,0,#},{#,#,#},r}&,1,#]&[3]//MatrixForm]

[image: Nest[ArrayFlatten@{r={#,0,#},{#,#,#},r}&,1,#]&[5]//Image]

Comment: what the heck of course Mathematica has a built-in for recursive nested arrays lol. +1

Comment: @HyperNeutrino well obviously

Comment: @HyperNeutrino How is this considered a built-in? Just `Nest` (repeatedly) the function multiple times. Like any other submissions (Jelly?) The `ArrayFlatten` is... well, built-in, but it behaves somewhat just like a `Flatten[#,{{1,3},{2,4}}]` in this case. (didn't test)

Comment: [There is a built-in for this, but longer.](https://tio.run/##DcixCoAgEADQXzkKmi7oaC4aGhsCRzGwKHLQQM8hxG@3pgfPar5Pq9kculwwQFl04EnEPbDhyOZx4g18WpmoHZMfEmGHlJE2jz7/Yq2aMj9y9caxdAgVtCNUCJd0SiGkv/qsygc "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") Mathematica has long function names.

Comment: How could it not, given its triumph at [the upgoat challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71680/20929)?

Answer (score 21):

### [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
H；［⌐⌐∔＊×∔；３＊＋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=SCV1RkYxQiV1RkYzQiV1RkYxQSV1RkYxQSV1RkYxQSV1RkYxMiV1RkYwQSVENyV1MjIxNCV1RkYxQiV1RkYxMyV1RkYwQSV1RkYwQg__,i=Mg__)

Explanation:

```
Code    |Instruction                                                         |Stack
--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------
        |Push input to stack (implicit)                                      |I
H       |Push "H" to stack                                                   |I,"H"
；      |Swap the top two stack items                                        |"H",I
［      |The following ToS (input) times:                                    |X
    ⌐⌐  |Duplicate ToS (result from last loop ("H" if first loop)) four times|X,X,X,X,X
    ∔   |Join vertically                                                     |X,X,X,X\nX
    ×   |Prepend                                                             |X,X,XX\nX
    ∔   |Join vertically                                                     |X,X\nXX\nX
    ；  |Swap top two stack items                                            |X\nXX\nX,X
    ３＊|Repeat three times vertically                                       |X\nXX\nX,X\nX\nX
    ＋  |Join horizontally                                                   |X<space>X\nXXX\nX<space>X
        |End loop (implicit)                                                 |X
        |Print ToS (implicit)                                                |
```

Where `I` is the input, `X` is the pattern generated by the previous loop ("H" for the first loop), and `<space>` is the empty space on the first and third row of the pattern, added implicitly by `＋`.

*-2 bytes thanks to [dzaima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59183/dzaima)!*

Comment: Amazingly short answer :O

Answer (score 19):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
t:"[ACA]BX*
```

Given input `n`,  this outputs a matrix containing `0` and `n`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8RKKdrR2THWKULr/39jAA)

To convert this into a character matrix of `H`and space add `g72*c` in the header. [Try it online too!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8RKKdrR2THWKULrf7q5kVbyf2MA)

Or add `]1YC` to see the matrix displayed graphically. Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=t%3A%22%5BACA%5DBX%2a%0A%5D1YG&inputs=3&version=20.8.0)

#### Explanation

```
t          % Input (implicit): n. Duplicate
:          % Range. Gives the array [ 1 2 ... n]
"          % For each (that is, do n times)
  [ACA]    %   Push the array [5 7 5]
  B        %   Convert to binary. Gives the 3×3 matrix [1 0 1; 1 1 1; 1 0 1]
  X*       %   Kronecker product
           % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 16):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <strike>16</strike> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╛c_mê║6{│◙ÖmπV"
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=be635f6d88ba367bb30a996de35622&i=2&a=1)

This is the ascii representation of the program with comments.  This program builds up the H sideways, and then transposes once at the end.

```
'H]                 ["H"]
   {         },*    repeat block specified number of times
    c               copy the matrix
     {3*m           triplicate each row
         |S         surround; prepend and append like b + a + b
           |C       horizontally center rows with spaces
                M   transpose back to original orientation
                 m  output each row
```

[Bonus 14 byte program](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ce104d969c6288969557af02b941&i=3&a=1) - uses its input as the output character.  Theoretically, this would not produce the right shape at 10, since it has 2 digits, but attempting to run that crashes my browser.

Answer (score 11):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 72 bytes

Output is a list of strings, one string per line.

```ruby
f=->n{n<1?[?H]:[*a=(x=f[n-1]).map{|i|i+' '*i.size+i},*x.map{|i|i*3},*a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs/G0D7a3iPWKlor0VajwjYtOk/XMFZTLzexoLomsyZTW11BXStTrzizKlU7s1ZHqwIuo2UM5CbG1v4vKC0pVkiLTk8tKdYryY/PjP1vCgA)

Comment: Well done! The output looks wrong on tio at first, but it's fine when zoomed out.

Answer (score 11):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

```apl
×/¨∘.≥⍨2|,⍳⎕⍴3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQZcjzra0/4fnq5/aMWjjhl6jzqXPupdYVSj86h3M1DNo94txv@BKv6ncRlzqatzpXEZQShDCGUAAA)

`⎕` evaluated input n

`,⍳⎕⍴3` all n-tuples with elements from 0 1 2

`2|` mod 2

`×/¨∘.≥⍨` form a matrix by comparing every pair of tuples a and b - if all elements of a are ≥ the corresponding elements of b, it's a 1, otherwise 0

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 50 bytes

```hs
f 0=[[1]]
f n=[x++map(*c)x++x|c<-[0,1,0],x<-f$n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BwDY62jA2litNIc82ukJbOzexQEMrWRPIqqhJttGNNtAx1DGI1amw0U1TydM1jP2fm5iZp2CrAFTnq1BQlJlXoqCikKZg/B8A)

Makes a grid of 0's and 1's. One character longer for spaces and H's.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 51 bytes

```hs
f 0=["H"]
f n=[x++map(min c)x++x|c<-" H ",x<-f$n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BwDZayUMplitNIc82ukJbOzexQCM3M08hWRPIqahJttFVUvBQUNKpsNFNU8nTNYz9n5sIlLZVACr0VSgoLQkuKfLJU1BRSFMw/g8A)

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
381B«€s3Z€ẎF€µ¡
```

This is a full program that prints a 2D array of **1**'s and **0**'s.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/YwtDp0OpHTWuKjaOA5MNdfW5A6tDWQwv/AyUB) or [see the output with **H**'s and spaces.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/YwtDp0OpHTWuKjaOA5MNdfW5A6tDWQwv/H25/uLv7UeM@D4VIoDoA)

Answer (score 8):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 126 bytes

```java
n->{int s=1,H[][]=new int[n+=Math.pow(3,n)-n][n],x;for(;s<n;s*=3)for(x=n*n;x-->0;)H[x/n][x%n]|=~(x/n/s%3)&x%n/s%3&1;return H;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVA9b8IwFNz5FU9IIOcT0nTCmLFKBybGKEMaEjANL1HsQChN/3pqBwpVu1TqYD3fvbPuzrv4EDu79WvH92VRSdgp7NaS525WYyJ5ga5JB0keCwHLmCOcBwDPKJ@u2zlHGUZhtIAMWIfO4qwIEMyzA00zTI@gJWixZSy3blkciW@j4WAUYmQ3NCsqQsUcqTCZb2jUMDSRNo6zmFIjCJuJkjYjjN7ZB1FgIka@MVaEvow9WqWyrhAC2nZUZSvrl5wnIGQs1TgUfA17nZusZMVxE0YQVxth9D0AtF8fmL@lzKP9hDkD/3K1rC8hwLUoBMBAt9K/QQw3c@OyzE9Eyw161ZbKSpLghlcnIdO9W9TS7Ve5evm/XTu4nO89L663nD86Kmo7u7P37s0Mtnf2t2lGhqNkaAPxnMYwH6eW/3AL2P4xaNt9Ag)

Returns an `int[][]` with `0` for `H` and `1` for `space`. This actually "carves" a wall of `H`'s instead of "piling" `H`'s.

### Explanations

```java
n->{                        // An int to int[][] lambda function
  int s=1,                  //  size of the carvings.
      H[][]=new int[n+=Math.pow(3,n)-n][n],  
                            //  change n to 3^n, through +=...-n to avoid an explicit cast
                            //  and create the 2D array to return, filled with 0s
      x;                    //  counter for the 2D array
  for(;s<n;s*=3)            //  for each size
    for(x=n*n;x-->0;)       //   for each cell
      H[x/n][x%n] |=        //     assign 1 to a cell of the array if...
        ~(x/n/s%3)          //      it is located in the "holes" of the H
        &x%n/s%3            //
        &1;                 //      
  return H;                 //  return the array
}                           // end the lambda
```

### Credits

- -9 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

Comment: save 5 bytes by adding a static import for Math.pow

Comment: @Selim the static import is required in the byte count. So I would lose...  19 bytes.

Answer (score 8):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
┌.{³2∙⁴┼+;3∙┼
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyNTBDLiU3QiVCMzIldTIyMTkldTIwNzQldTI1M0MrJTNCMyV1MjIxOSV1MjUzQw__,inputs=Mw__,v=0.12)

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 64 bytes

```r
function(n)Reduce(`%x%`,rep(list(matrix(c(1,1,1,0,1,0),3,3)),n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BC8IwDIXv/opQERqsoOyoP2Bnr6JsdCkrzHRkGZu/vnZKyCHvhfc@yQFuJ8hhZq8xsWW8Uzd7ss1hPTROaLRDnNS@W5W4Wm8vbpvztugqVyE6Rsy8xVSwh4kUGHoSuoL2BELvNnJHAin8hJCSlmuJwwCjRFZIs/6cfwf4JEJeh0/50R5qaLmDaWw97RaJSgXCgHGmNvhQGwry8YLPAlS92DljMH8B)

Reduces by Kronecker product, as a shameless port of [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157697/67312).

The footer prints the result nicely, but this is an anonymous function which returns a `matrix` of `1` for `H` and `0` for space.

Answer (score 7):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 22 bytes

```
éHÀñäLgvr PGï3PkyHGpH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BKj8MNhzceXiLmk15WpBDgfni9cUB2pYd7gcf///9NAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: e948 c0f1 e416 4c67 7672 2050 47ef 3350  .H....Lgvr PG.3P
00000010: 6b79 4847 7048                           kyHGpH
```

This is basically the exact same approach as [the Sierpinski carpet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126218/31716) and [The Fractal Plus](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Fractal+Plus) on Anarchy Golf.

Comment: Is that French?

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes

```python
f=lambda r:-r*'H'or[x+[x,' '*3**r][b]+x for b in 1,0,1for x in f(r-1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcgxCoAgGAbQq/ybaQZZW9DeHcQhCUkolQ8DO70hje@lN58xTLW69dpve@yEZYBgG4vQpddFMmJiFgJGW9MXchFkyQdScpSqqTS5DoPiprbAHz6kJ3ecLwk@ZEKdPw)

Function outputs a list of strings.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 84 bytes

```python
r=input()
for i in range(3**r):x,s=' H';exec"s+=[x,s][i%3%2]+s;x*=3;i/=3;"*r;print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixCoAgEADQva84gqg0CHJLbu8fwiHC6pZLTgP7emt5wwtvum6eShEkDk/q@uq4BQiIQTY@fWeUkn7OQ8QWltb67Pc6alz/cSs1ppmcjjYrNJbGn1qJDUKcIJZiPg)

Uses the same template as other 3*3 fractal patterns:

- [Sierpinski
  carpet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143780/20260)
- [Fractal
  X](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Fractal+X/xnor_1471571069&py)
- [Fractal plus](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Fractal%20Plus).

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
,./^:2@(*/#:@5 7 5)^:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0FHTz/OyshBQ0tf2crBVMFcwVQzzir2f2pyRr5CmoIRF4ihoa7goV5dp@WQpqmmZ6dgrGCkYPgfAA)

```
        */               multiply by
          #:@5 7 5       the binary matrix shaped like H
,./^:2                   assemble the 4-dimensional result into a matrix
                   ^:]   do it input times
```

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, <s>73</s> <s>67</s> <s>64</s> 55 bytes

```
g#f=g<>f<>g
w=map.(id#)
(iterate(w(>>" ")#w id)["H"]!!)
```

This works only with the latest version of `Prelude`, because it exports `<>` from `Data.Semigroup`. To run it on TIO, add an import as done here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDoMgEADQ3a84oQMsLq7C5ODQTo6mMZcI9FJRgmf4fNq3vw9eX7fvlWI6M8OIjN3sIoV83qkG6U0YrB9saIqJmDpFm9SNN4rYZWSnirJWgNCyAG16EZN4t62uEekAA//yWiHdPHN@HvAAD339AQ)

```
g#f=              -- function # takes two functions g and f and a list s
                  -- and returns
   g <> f <> g    -- g(s), followed by f(s) and another g(s)

w=                -- w takes a function and a list of lists
                  -- (both as unnamed parameters, because of pointfree style,
                  -- so let's call them f and l)
  map.(id#)       -- return map(id#f)l, i.e. apply (id#f) to every element of l

  w(>>" ")#w id   -- this partial application of # is a function that
                  -- takes the missing list (here a list of lists)
                  -- remember: (>>" ") is the function that replaces every element
                  -- of a list with a single space

iterate(   )["H"] -- starting with a singleton list of the string "H"
                  -- which itself is a singleton list of the char 'H'
                  -- repeatedly apply the above function
              !!  -- and pick the nth iteration



Example for ["H H", "HHH", "H H"], i.e.

   H H
   HHH
   H H

call the iterated function:
                    ( w(>>" ")         # w id       ) ["H H","HHH","H H"]

expand w:           ( map(id#(>>" "))  # map(id#id) ) ["H H","HHH","H H"]

expand outermost #: map(id#(>>" "))["H H","HHH","H H"] ++
                    map(id#id)     ["H H","HHH","H H"] ++
                    map(id#(>>" "))["H H","HHH","H H"]

expand map:         [(id#(>>" "))"H H",   (id#(>>" "))"HHH",   (id#(>>" "))"H H"] ++
                    [(id#id)     "H H",   (id#id)     "HHH",   (id#id)     "H H"] ++
                    [(id#(>>" "))"H H",   (id#(>>" "))"HHH",   (id#(>>" "))"H H"]

expand other #:     ["H H"++"   "++"H H", "HHH"++"   "++"HHH", "H H"++"   "++"H H"] ++
                    ["H H"++"H H"++"H H", "HHH"++"HHH"++"HHH", "H H"++"H H"++"H H"] ++
                    ["H H"++"   "++"H H", "HHH"++"   "++"HHH", "H H"++"   "++"H H"]

collaps ++:         ["H H   H H", "HHH   HHH", "H H   H H",
                     "H HH HH H", "HHHHHHHHH", "H HH HH H",
                     "H H   H H", "HHH   HHH", "H H   H H"]

which is printed line by line: 

  H H   H H
  HHH   HHH
  H H   H H
  H HH HH H
  HHHHHHHHH
  H HH HH H
  H H   H H
  HHH   HHH
  H H   H H
```

Edit: -9 bytes thanks to @Potato44.

Comment: You should be able to golf `(#)` down to `g#f=g<>f<>g` if you use GHC 8.4. This is because `Semigroup` is now in the prelude.

Comment: @Potato44: I'm pretty sure this will help in a lot of challenges. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Vim - <strike>66</strike> <strike>56</strike> 54 bytes

<kbd>A</kbd>
<kbd>@</kbd>
<kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>H</kbd>
<kbd>esc</kbd>
<kbd>"</kbd>
<kbd>r</kbd>
<kbd>d</kbd>
<kbd>^</kbd>
<kbd>q</kbd>
<kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>{</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl-v</kbd>
<kbd>}</kbd>
<kbd>"</kbd>
<kbd>a</kbd>
<kbd>y</kbd>
<kbd>g</kbd>
<kbd>v</kbd>
<kbd>r</kbd>
<kbd>space</kbd>
<kbd>g</kbd>
<kbd>v</kbd>
<kbd>d</kbd>
<kbd>"</kbd>
<kbd>a</kbd>
<kbd>P</kbd>
<kbd>P</kbd>
<kbd>"</kbd>
<kbd>a</kbd>
<kbd>P</kbd>
<kbd>V</kbd>
<kbd>G</kbd>
<kbd>"</kbd>
<kbd>b</kbd>
<kbd>y</kbd>
<kbd>P</kbd>
<kbd>g</kbd>
<kbd>v</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl-v</kbd>
<kbd>$</kbd>
<kbd>d</kbd>
<kbd>"</kbd>
<kbd>a</kbd>
<kbd>P</kbd>
<kbd>.</kbd>
<kbd>.</kbd>
<kbd>G</kbd>
<kbd>"</kbd>
<kbd>b</kbd>
<kbd>p</kbd>
<kbd>q</kbd>
<kbd>@</kbd>
<kbd>r</kbd>

The input is taken as a number in the buffer.

Comment: What do I have to type, starting from a bash prompt, assuming I have vim installed, to see the result?

Comment: Type vim, press enter, type the input number (e.g. 3) in the buffer then, from normal mode, press the sequence of keys from the post.

Comment: Make sure to use vanilla vim

Comment: There was a typo in the code. Just fixed it.

Comment: Works! <kbd>I</kbd> is a capital i, not ell. `:set nowrap` to see the result, for 4 and more.

Comment: @Fabien an `i` works as well, so I changed it to be more clear

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>46</s> <s>44</s> <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

1 based counting. Uses `0` and `1` for `H` and space, has a leading `1` (space)

```perl
say//,map/$'/^1,@;for@;=glob"{A,.,A}"x<>
```

Based on a classic idea by mtve.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJfXyc3sUBfRV0/zlDHwTotv8jB2jY9Jz9JqdpRR0/HsVapwsbu/3/jf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwN9AwA)

Comment: Output for n ≥ 3 isn't quite right.

Comment: @primo The program was correct but TIO uses the UTF-8 version of the special characters. I fixed the link to use escapes instead, but the program still works if you use the actual literal characters

Comment: I have no idea why `\321` is necessary, any character seems to work. `//` and `$'` can also replace `//g` and `$\``, but I'm not sure it leads to an improvement.

Comment: @primo Thanks! I was still working from code derived from the old mtve solution where `\321` was the bit complement of `.` (used to generate another fractal pattern). But I dropped the bit-complement so of course I don't need that anymore. I used `//g` and $` so I can easily test the code from the commandline (`//` and `$'` don't lead to a gain I can see, the gained byte is wasted with a space or `!` again)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 143 bytes

```python
def g(a,x,y,s):
	if s:s/=3;[g(a,x+k/3*s,y+k%3*s,s)for k in 0,2,3,4,5,6,8]
	else:a[x][y]=1
def f(s):s=3**s;a=eval("s*[0],"*s);g(a,0,0,s);print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/daoMwFL72PEUIDKKG1tVuDMWL3u0dRCRY02Y6I550rU/vTnQw2MhFPs75/s44u6sdDov5HO3kGM4I0PQKkZ0yCM6tZnVtBuPqWmDb65CGgQc7dJMZLqxgnG@8@2Rcu5IkQ3fT/7lxsS0AFOlOIgSw/ZkgpRLnbG8O4BfTQi3e@SKUfMhZonc0mmGG@yLNy3Ued/s0QjnH3ZP/MdR2Yh0zA0vkQabyKF/kq3yrIGh7bDNVPqpyropn8M5akCcWaRRhror2S/WCY1QmleQRhrkPSOgRHOkCR320OIZ/StINAD51snefu9qon6N95U3L@e7DmkFw9s7LpmJe0Xg@ycLlGw)

-30 bytes thanks to recursive

wrapper code is for nice formatting. it works fine if you remove it

Comment: [A few golfs](https://tio.run/##HU5LDoIwFFzDKZomJm15EbBqDATX3oGwaGJRhFDShwqnx1czi5nF/KZ1frpRb9vdtuwhDCywAsoijrqW4TUnEWGaVpq4dZ71rBtFBgfQcIQTnOEii38s6dNUK4Q16XeBUcaRHdAWpl6aem2qPA4TraByrLRSWJrKfswgOKo6a4ArlGWoyggkvZ3ffmRmC7PefWmY0jpcm3w3zoLz/cvRG85uvLYNCz4bXGSWcvsB)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <strike>38</strike> 34 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
({(⍵,(0×⍵),⍵){⍺⍪⍵⍪⍺}⍵,⍵,⍵}⍣⎕)1 1⍴1
```

Output is a 2-dimensional array with `1` representing H and `0` representing space.

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7B%28%7B%28%u2375%2C%280%D7%u2375%29%2C%u2375%29%7B%u237A%u236A%u2375%u236A%u237A%7D%u2375%2C%u2375%2C%u2375%7D%u2363%u2375%291%201%u23741%7D&run)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can omit `f←` and count chars as 1 byte each: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each It's also considered legal to take input from `⎕`, i.e. replace `⍣⍵` with `⍣⎕` and drop the outer dfn's braces.

Comment: Thanks! I've never actually formally golfed APL before so these should help.

Comment: `1 1⍴1` can be written as `⍪1` and then the parens around the operator become unnecessary. If you're familiar with [trains](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl/43084#43084) - they can help a lot here.

Comment: Also, `⍨` is your friend: `(⍵,(0×⍵),⍵)` => `(⍵,⍵,⍨0×⍵)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
HＦＥＮＸ³ι«Ｊ⁰¦⁰Ｃ⁰ιＣιιＴ⊗ι⊗ι‖ＯＯ→↓ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCoMwFETXeorg6gdSENzZZV20hbYiXiDaWD9EfwiJUkrPniqVdjXvMcy0vbQtSR1CaXF0kBwTvo87sgwu0sBpNN5d/dAoC1ywkuYFMsGQc85ecXT2g6kJUsHSZRYdyDxXwZ/gJrXFAQryjVZ3wOXqz2tdqU6r1t0mZbU0W0Be4aN3guUFzeP36B1CFnaT/gA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
H
```

Print the original `H`.

```
ＦＥＮＸ³ι«
```

Loop over the first `size` powers of 3.

```
Ｊ⁰¦⁰
```

Move the cursor back to the origin. `Trim` needs this, as both the original printing of the `H` and the reflection below move the cursor.

```
Ｃ⁰ι
```

Copy the previous iteration downwards, creating a domino.

```
Ｃιι
```

Copy the result down and right, creating a tetromino.

```
Ｔ⊗ι⊗ι
```

Trim the canvas down to an `L` shape triomino.

```
‖ＯＯ→↓ι
```

Reflect the canvas horizontally and vertically with overlap, completing the iteration.

Charcoal is better at some fractals than others. Here's a similar idea, but in almost half the size:

```
HＦＮ«⟲Ｃ²⁶‖ＯＯLＸ³ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJQ0nTmistv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NToZqLMyi/JLEk1Tm/oFLDyAyojDMoNS0nNbnEvyy1KCexAEppWPnoKATklwO1GesoZGoCFdb@/2/8X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP 7, <s>125</s> 109 bytes

a different approach: Instead of nesting and flattening the result recursively, this just loops through the rows and columns and uses a 3rd loop to find out if to print `H` or `_`.

Edit: Saved a lot by combining the row/column loops to one, though it took a bit to get the decrease for the inner loop correct. Requires PHP 7 for the power operator.

[Try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/447783049bb371196e0235947b591123f9fe0e9a)!

---

```php
for($z=3**$argn;$z*$z>$q=$p;print$c."
"[++$p%$z])for($c=H;$q;$q-=$q/$z%3*$z,$q/=3)if($q%3==1&&$q/$z%3-1)$c=_;
```

prints the result. Run as pipe with `-nR`.

### qualified function, <s>147</s> 130 bytes

```php
function r($n){for($z=3**$n;$z*$z>$q=$p;$r.=$c."
"[++$p%$z])for($c=H;$q;$q-=$q/$z%3*$z,$q/=3)if($q%3==1&&$q/$z%3-1)$c=_;return$r;}
```

returns a single string. Run with default config (no `php.ini`).

Comment: `%3==1` can be replaced with `%3&1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
,’b3U×"3S_4A1e
3*çþ`ị⁾ HY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//LOKAmWIzVcOXIjNTXzRBMWUKMyrDp8O@YOG7i@KBviBIWf///zQ)

---

Although this is longer than the [existing Jelly submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157670/), it tries to generate each character independently just from the coordinate.

In particular, if the coordinate is `(x,y)` (1-indexing), the first link returns `0` and `1` corresponds to `H` and   respectively.

```
,                Pair. Get (x,y)
 ’               Decrement. Get (x,y) (0-indexing)
  b3             Convert to base 3 digits.
    U            Upend. So next operations can pair the corresponding digits.
     ×"3         Multiply the first element (list) by 3.
        S        Sum (corresponding digit together). Let the sum be s.
         _4A1e   Check if any of abs(s-4) is 1. Equivalently, check
                 if there is any 3 or 5 in the list of s.
```

Also, the 5 bytes `ị⁾ HY` are used for formatting, so this program (20 bytes) is also valid (but the output doesn't look as nice):

```
,’b3U×"3S_4A1e
3*çþ`
```

Answer (score 3):

## [T-SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/sql-server), <s>267</s> 261 bytes

```
DECLARE @N INT=3DECLARE @ TABLE(I INT,H VARCHAR(MAX))INSERT @ VALUES(1,'H H'),(2,'HHH'),(3,'H H');WITH
T AS(SELECT 1 A,3 P,I J,H S FROM @ UNION ALL SELECT A+1,P*3,J*P+I,REPLACE(REPLACE(S,' ','   '),'H',H)FROM @,T
WHERE A<@N)SELECT S FROM T WHERE A=@N ORDER BY J
```

Comment: This is my first answer on Code Golf, so please help me if I made any mistakes. Also, my preferred language is Transact-SQL, which is not very suitable for short code.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and nice first post! For tips about golfing in T-SQL, make sure to check out [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32796/66833) post!

Comment: I tried adding a sqlfiddle, but it doesn't work well with table variables. If I use normal tables, it's even 1 byte shorter: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb14e/2. However, the output is not formatted correctly by sqlfiddle, but it works fine in SSMS.

Comment: You should be able to get this down to 259 by removing some unnecessary whitespace and linefeeds

Comment: I only got to 261. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 7, 153 bytes

```php
    function p($n){$r=["H H",HHH,"H H"];if(--$n)foreach(p($n)as$s){$r[+$i]=$r[$i+6*$p=3**$n]=str_pad($s,2*$p).$s;$r[3*$p+$i++]=$s.$s.$s;}ksort($r);return$r;}
```

Run with default config (no `php.ini`) or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/58d2dc212341fc0beb36b00d8ce44ced12e23116).

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 64 bytes

```perl
//;$_ x=3,$.=s|.+|$&@{[$$_++/$.&1?$&:$"x$.]}$&|g for($_=H.$/)x$'
```

Requires `-p`, input is taken from stdin. Output is an H of `H`s.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCkAwFAbgV5H@hsZZkhtaXHoHaVdIyRYuVubVHd/n5nOvmZVqYSKvqxykr0AyQPTPCBgpFUiUHUSD2IOmFyKs0WLPFEYPBJV5JMzVZ9292ePiwv0)

Comment: Counting on this site has changed, you don't need to count `-p` anymore (I think it is too  lenient for perl, but that's how it is now)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP (5.6+), 94 bytes

```php
<?for(;$H>$e*=3or$e=($i+=$e&&print"$s
")<${$s=H}=3**$argn;)$s.=str_pad($i/$e%3&1?$s:'',$e).$s;
```

Used with `-F` command line option. Assumes interpreter defaults (`-n`). Will not work on versions previous to 5.6, due to the power operator.

**Sample usage**

```php
$ echo 3|php -nF h-carpet.php
H H   H H         H H   H H
HHH   HHH         HHH   HHH
H H   H H         H H   H H
H HH HH H         H HH HH H
HHHHHHHHH         HHHHHHHHH
H HH HH H         H HH HH H
H H   H H         H H   H H
HHH   HHH         HHH   HHH
H H   H H         H H   H H
H H   H HH H   H HH H   H H
HHH   HHHHHH   HHHHHH   HHH
H H   H HH H   H HH H   H H
H HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH H
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
H HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH H
H H   H HH H   H HH H   H H
HHH   HHHHHH   HHHHHH   HHH
H H   H HH H   H HH H   H H
H H   H H         H H   H H
HHH   HHH         HHH   HHH
H H   H H         H H   H H
H HH HH H         H HH HH H
HHHHHHHHH         HHHHHHHHH
H HH HH H         H HH HH H
H H   H H         H H   H H
HHH   HHH         HHH   HHH
H H   H H         H H   H H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDsIgEAXQvcdovrSg1hh20rE701uYJo7KBiYMO@PVRd/@yUtam@ZHLkPAcgE78rmAaUDcEdgYKTHVDrrp7IQ3lJYPeeewlmcKFjqS1nKT9f4fR/DWm9MMPff9HmxHaGjNf7PUmJO2Q7r@AA)

Comment: You can save one byte: `$s.$s.$s` instead of `$s.=$s.$s`. And you don´t need `<?` with `-R` instead of `-F`.

Comment: Thanks for the byte. Regarding `-R`, can you show me the complete usage?

Comment: Just like `-nF`: `echo <input> | php -nR '<code>'`. `-r` is almost the same: `php -nr '<code>' <arguments>`.

Comment: Maybe I'm just too stupid to get it working :/ https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqpmk.png

Comment: Errm no, sorry. The mix of quotation marks ruins it. You probably _could_ work around that with a `~` for the preg-replacement; but that would render your code pretty unreadable - for gaining a single byte.

Comment: But: why `preg_filter` and not simply `$s=($s=$s.$s).sprintf("%$i.s$s",$$i++/$i&1?$s:"");`? And have you tried `$s.str_pad($$i++/$i&1?$s:"",$i).$s` instead of the `sprintf`? (I have not)

Comment: `preg_filter` is to iterate each line while preserving newlines, roughly equivalent to `join("\n",array_map(function(){...},split("\n",$s.$s.$s)))`, but significantly less verbose. I initially had `str_pad` but changed to `sprintf` because it's one byte shorter: `'"\0".str_pad($$i++/$i&1?"\0":"",$i)."\0"'`

Answer (score 1):

## CJam - <strike>103</strike> <strike>97</strike> <strike>87</strike> 76 bytes

```
{H{ae_,S*}%}:Il~a:A];{A_W={)(a9*+:A;[[HIH][HHH][HIH]]{z~}%}{);:A;"H"}?}:H~N*
```

This program does a quite verbose "handcoded" recursion. No smart matrix multiplications. Throughout the recursion, on top of the stack there is an array gathering the output gained from the parent calls. Right after each set of recursive calls the output of the recursive calls needs to be zipped together, to make sure the output is correct when the stack is printed linearly at the end of the program. The stack of arguments being passed down the recursion is kept in the variable `A`.

[Try online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7BH%7Bae_%2CS*%7D%25%7D%3AIl~a%3AA%5D%3B%7BA_W%3D%7B)(a9*%2B%3AA%3B%5B%5BHIH%5D%5BHHH%5D%5BHIH%5D%5D%7Bz~%7D%25%7D%7B)%3B%3AA%3B%22H%22%7D%3F%7D%3AH~N*&input=4)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://github.com/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
{~|/a<\:'a:1=!x#3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrquRj/RJsZKPdHK0FaxQtm49n@agiFXmoIREBv/BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 23 bytes

```
_·£[X³XX³]Ãy c ·û}gQq)y
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=I1tvX2QjJCBrIltvX2QkazEhIjE=&input=)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
Z{ZqR mXYZ{[Xp3 XXp3]} y c qR û}gQq)y

Z{    Declare a function that accepts a string...
  ZqR   Split by newline...
  mXYZ{   and map each row into...
    [Xp3 XXp3]  an array of [X.repeat(3), X, X.repeat(3)]
  }
  y   Transpose the resulting 2D array
  c   Flatten
  qR  Join with newline
  û   Center-pad each row to the longest
}
gQq)  Apply the above function to '"' recursively
y     Transpose the resulting 2D string
```

Using the transposed pattern

```
III
 I 
III
```

is far easier to handle than the original `H` pattern, at least in Japt where the `I` can be done with string repeat and center-padding.

Answer (score 0):

## C++11 - 138 bytes

Not sure if this answer has a valid syntax here however.

```
#define A a?1:0
template<int N>struct H{H<N-1>h[9];H(int a):h{A,0,A,A,A,A,A,0,A}{}};template<>struct H<0>{char h;H(int a):h{a?'H':' '}{}};
```

Ungolfed with working code

```
#include <iostream>

#define A a?1:0

template<int N>
struct H
{
  H<N-1> h[9];

  H(int a) : h{A,0,A,A,A,A,A,0,A}
  {}
};

template<>
struct H<0>
{
  char h;

  H(int a) : h{a?'H':' '}
  {}
};

int pow(int a, int b)
{
  int res=1;

  for (int i=1; i<=b; ++i)
    res *= a;

  return res;
}

template<int N>
char getHvalue(int i, int j, H<N> &hn)
{
  int n3=pow(3, N-1);

//std::cout << N << " " << i << " " << j << std::endl;

  return getHvalue(i%n3, j%n3, hn.h[i/n3*3+j/n3]);
}

template<>
char getHvalue<0>(int, int, H<0> &hn)
{
  return hn.h;
}

int main()
{
  H<0> h0(1);

  std::cout << getHvalue(0, 0, h0) << std::endl;

  std::cout << "\n====================\n" << std::endl;

  H<1> h1(1);

  for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<3; ++j)
      std::cout << getHvalue(i, j, h1);
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "\n====================\n" << std::endl;

  H<2> h2(1);

  for (int i=0; i<9; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<9; ++j)
      std::cout << getHvalue(i, j, h2);
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "\n====================\n" << std::endl;

  H<3> h3(1);

  for (int i=0; i<27; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<27; ++j)
      std::cout << getHvalue(i, j, h3);
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```