# Eiffel Towers: Create a large "A" from "A"s

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Create a function which given a number of lines `n`, makes a `bigA`.

- The horizontal bar of `bigA` must be at the middle row, or the lower of the two if `n` is even
- Assume a monospace font for output

Output should be a string (or similar, eg character array) with clear linebreaks to break up the lines, and with correct whitespace for left-padding (you can assume \t to be 4 spaces). There can be any whitespace on the right.

### Examples

#### n = 1

`A`

#### n = 2

```
 A
AAA
```

#### n = 3

```
  A
 AAA
A   A
```

#### n = 4

```
   A
  A A
 AAAAA
A     A
```

#### n = 5

```
    A
   A A
  AAAAA
 A     A
A       A
```

This is inspired by [Create an "H" from smaller "H"s](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157664/create-an-h-from-smaller-hs)

Comment: May I add whitespace to the right side? Also, is trailing newline allowed?

Comment: @Bubbler, Any whitespace on the right side is fine, no trailing newline though

Comment: Are we allowed to return 2D character arrays instead of strings? (hint: it's usually recommended to allow any kind of output)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Sure, as long as there is a clear break for the lines (eg an "\n" element, nested arrays)

Comment: Is an array of strings representing lines ok? Also, can I print directly to stdout?

Comment: Yes, output is flexible as long as spacing and newlines are clearly represented somehow

Comment: Can we use another content character than "A" ? in particular, is lowercase "a" allowed ?

Comment: @TonHospel, No, that really defeats the purporse of this

Comment: Can `____A\bA____` be used instead of `____A____` ? `\b` stands for ASCII backspace character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

#### Code:

```
Ð;î¹)'A1376SΛ
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8ATrw@sO7dRUdzQ0NjcLPjf7/39zAA)

#### Explanation:

```
Ð                  # Triplicate the input.
 ;î                # Compute ceiling(n / 2).
   ¹               # Push the first input again.
    )              # Wrap into an array. For input 7, this would result in:
                     [7, 7, 4, 7].
     'A            # Push the character 'A'
       1376S       # Push the array [1, 3, 7, 6]. These are the directions of the canvas.
                     This essentially translates to [↗, ↘, ↖, ←].
            Λ      # Write to canvas using the previous three parameters.
```

#### Canvas

I should probably document the canvas a little bit more (and a lot of other functions), but this basically sums it up. The canvas has different 'modes' based on the parameter types given. The canvas command has three parameters: **<length> <string> <direction>**.

Since the length and direction parameters are lists, it 'zips' these lists to create a set of instructions to be executed. The string parameter is just the letter **A**, so this is the fill character used by all instructions. The canvas interprets this as the following set of instructions (for input 7):

- Draw a line of length **7** with the string **A** in direction **↗**
- Draw a line of length **7** with the string **A** in direction **↘**
- Draw a line of length **4** with the string **A** in direction **↖**
- Draw a line of length **7** with the string **A** in direction **←**

The directions are translated in the following manner:

```
7   0   1
  ↖ ↑ ↗
6 ← X → 2
  ↙ ↓ ↘
5   4   3
```

If nothing has been outputted, 05AB1E automatically outputs the canvas result.

Comment: Thank you very much for the canvas explanation, that's a brilliant feature :-)

Comment: TIL triplicate is a word

Comment: @thecoder16 quadruplicate, quintuplicate, ..., decuplicate

Comment: Wow. I was doubtful of nonuplicate, but it exists as all the others do. Of course we have such useless words in English xD

Comment: `1376` can be `Ž5'` now. (Thanks for adding `Ž`, very useful!) Btw, the docs for the Canvas are still missing. ;) It's one of the few features for which I still have to look at the Elixir source code in order to fully see its capabilities. Especially since crosses are also possible with `+` or `×`. PS: Would like to see a box single-char as well. And it would be useful if multiple characters could be mixed somehow, like `-` and `|`, or `\` and `/`, or a box with `+` at the corners, etc. But that's perhaps something for later.

Comment: If you don't have time, let me know. Then I will add it to the 05AB1E tip page for now. I see it can also be used cyclic, as you've done in [this answer to create a spiral](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167486/52210). Didn't knew Canvas could even be used like that!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Hey, apologies for all the late replies, it's been incredibly busy for me the last couple of weeks (I only managed to get 8 hours of sleep the last 72 hours haha) so I don't think I'm able to do anything right now, but feel free to add it to the tip page if you'd like.

Comment: @Adnan [Created the tip.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210) If you see anything incorrect or something else worth mentioning, let me know. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
ＮθＰ×θAＭ⊘θ↗Ｐ^×θA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05rLtzSnJLOgKDOvRCMkMze1WKNQR0HJUUkTJJVflqrhkZhTlpoCVKqjYBVaEJSZnlGCqssqTkcBTef//yb/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
Ｐ×θA
```

Print the horizontal bar of the big `A`. (For even numbers, the `n+1`th overlaps the right side anyway.)

```
Ｍ⊘θ↗
```

Move to the top of the big `A`.

```
Ｐ^×θA
```

Print both sides of the big `A`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 80 bytes

```python
lambda n:'\n'.join(' '*(n+~i)+('A'+' A'[i==n/2]*n*2)[:i*2]+'A'for i in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcoxDsIwDEbhq3iznSCgGSNl6DnaDkEQMII/VdSFhauHzqzve@tne1SEXtLcX/l9uWZC5Bl8fFaDMLET@K@pFx7ZM408WUo4hcXBBZ2iubD43UptZGSglnG/CVT7XxoOw1nj2gybFLF9@AE)

Divide the desired output into the left whitespace, left `A` plus middle whitespace or `A`s, and the right `A`. Compute the middle part using slicing on a fixed string. This allows to use the same way to generate the first line.

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
┴3╬*ôP^x'┌_╓J²♫
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=c133ce2a93505e7827da5fd64afd0e&i=1%0A2%0A4%0A5&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, the program looks like this.

```
m       map over [1 .. input] using rest of the program, output each result
'A      "A" literal
xhi=    is the iteration index equal to (integer) half the input?
65*     multiply by 65 (character code of "A")
]i*     repeat that character (" " or  "A") i times
+       concat to initial "A"
x)      left pad to the original input
|p      palindromize (concatenate the reverse minus the last character)
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=m+++%09map+over+[1+..+input]+using+rest+of+the+program,+output+each+result%0A%27A++%09%22A%22+literal%0Axhi%3D%09is+the+iteration+index+equal+to+%28integer%29+half+the+input%3F%0A65*+%09multiply+by+65+%28character+code+of+%22A%22%29%0A]i*+%09repeat+that+character+%28%22+%22+or++%22A%22%29+i+times%0A%2B+++%09concat+to+initial+%22A%22%0Ax%29++%09left+pad+to+the+original+input%0A%7Cp++%09palindromize+%28concatenate+the+reverse+minus+the+last+character%29&i=1%0A2%0A4%0A5&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes

This source code has a [rectangle shape](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/160034/58563)! Oh wait ... wrong challenge :-/

```javascript
f=(n,k=n>>1,p='A')=>--n?f(n,k,' '+p)+`
${p}${(k-n?' ':'A').repeat(n*2-1)}A`:p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxCoMwFEDR3a/oICSvSYTYdhGS4n90MNiktMrLQ6WL@O2pjoWs596P@7q5n960KIxPn1IwHOVg0FotybCWgbFK4T0cLNmJCQLRFeVKW7nyYS@7NcdXTZ68Wziea6Vha7uGUh9xjqOvxvjigWsQ7IEMin@u83zJ8zXPN4D0Aw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/), 79 bytes or 73 bytes

Using **f-strings** to align horizontal parts of the letter:

```python
lambda n:'\n'.join(f"{'A'+' A'[i==n//2]*2*i:>{n+i}}"[:-1]+'A'for i in range(n))
```

With `\b` used to delete one `A` (possibly cheating):

```python
lambda n:'\n'.join(f"{'A'+' A'[i==n//2]*2*i:>{n+i}}\bA"for i in range(n))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 121 bytes

```java
n->{var a=new char[n][n+n-1];for(int c=n*n,r,q;c-->0;a[r=c%n][q=c/n]=a[r][n+n-q-2]+=r==n/2&q>=r|r==n+~q?65:32);return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNT4NAEL3zKyYkNVAK/TB66HYxxsTEg6cekcO6hboVBphdamqtf71uC40HPUzezL73dj42YivCzer9qMq6IgMbW0etUUU0ZM6ft7xFaVSF/5LaUCbKE@XIQmgNz0Ih7B2Aun0tlARthLGwrdQKSst5S0MK10kKgtbaP0sBntA89m0W8k1QkiZpDDnwI4bxfisIBMfsA84cpgkGGE5TllfkKTQgOQ5xRKOGyTCMJ0wkxOXA6houx5hyW3eeJpylASfOcTy7amJOX6c8@G7ubm/m1zOfUWZaQhDscGTnyS4tFHCYMgsLixObBMFleIDLyECZbgtjpXkk6rrYecpnvabbG7Ql74nETve38zqPH5Wi7o8zn9td/UhWRZFJ4z10WJGONpVCK/DcF3T936932mRlVLUmqq3f5J67VJ/ZHAarAQ60DXRHagS6dxycUxxO6fEH)

### Credits

- -3 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 65 bytes

```
f=:3 :''' A''{~1(([:(<@;]+i.@+:)<.@-:)y)}([:(}:@|."1,.])=/~@i.)y'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WyljBSl1dXcFRXb26zlBDI9pKw8bBOlY7U89B20rTRs9B10qzUrMWJF5r5VCjp2Sooxeraatf55Cpp1mp/j81OSNfIU3BiAvKMIUxDA3@AwA)

It can be reduced by approx. 12 bytes by simply making the verb tacit, but I have problems doing it.

### Explanation:

`3 : '...'` denotes an explicit one-liner verb

`y` is the argument

`=/~@i.` creates an identity matrix with size the argument

```
    =/~@i. 4
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

`([:(}:@|."1,.])` prepends the identity matrix with its mirror copy with last elements of each row dropped.

```
    ]a =. ([:(}:@|."1,.])=/~@i.) 4
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

`1(...)}(...)` changes to 1 the positions in its right argument, selected by the left one

`([:(<@;]+i.@+:)<.@-:)` - prepares the selection by doing the following:

```
               <.@-: - halves the argument and finds the floor (finds the row number)
    <@;              - box the row, followed by a list of columns:  
        ]+i.@+:      - a list form the argumnt to the doubled row number

    ([:(<@;]+i.@+:)<.@-:) 4
┌───────────┐
│┌─┬───────┐│
││2│2 3 4 5││
│└─┴───────┘│
└───────────┘

    1(([:(<@;]+i.@+:)<.@-:) 4)}a
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

`' A'{~` renders a space in the places of 0 and 'A' where there is 1

```
    ' A'{~1(([:(<@;]+i.@+:)<.@-:) 4)}a
   A   
  A A  
 AAAAA 
A     A
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>17</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
A×／╶½A×╶»╵：╋│
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=QSVENyV1RkYwRiV1MjU3NiVCREElRDcldTI1NzYlQkIldTI1NzUldUZGMUEldTI1NEIldTI1MDI_,i=MTQ_)

*-4 bytes thanks to [dzaima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59183/dzaima)!*

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
Çç" A"gZ¶Uz¹i'A êÃû
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=x+ciIEEiZ1q2VXq5aSdBIOrD+w==&input=OAotUg==)

---

### Explanation

```
                        :Implicit input of integer U
Ç                       :Create the range [0,U) and pass each Z through a function
         Uz             :  Floor divide U by 2
       Z¶               :  Test for equality with Z (true=1, false=0)
  " A"g                 :  Get the character in the string " A" at that index
 ç                      :  Repeat Z times
           ¹            :  (Closes a few nested methods)
            i'A         :  Prepend an "A"
                ê       :  Palindromise
                 Ã      :End function
                  û     :Centre pad each element to the length of the longest element
                        :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

---

### Alternative

(In the hope that it might help me spot some savings!)

```
Æ'AúXÄ" A"gX¶Uz¹êÃû
```

Comment: Another alternate that's a byte longer: `ç h'AUz)¬íp ®i'A êÃû`

Comment: @ETHproductions Replace `p `with `²` and it's also 19 bytes.

Comment: +1 way better than [my monstrosity](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=x6VVeiA/J0FwMStVeik6J0ErWu4p6sP7&input=NgoKLVI=).

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
 A*:╚╥≤.»I:ž
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTIwQSolM0EldTI1NUEldTI1NjUldTIyNjQuJUJCSSUzQSV1MDE3RQ__,inputs=NA__,v=0.12)

Explanation:

```
 A*           repeat "A" input times
   :          duplicate it
    ╚         create a "/" diagonal of one of the copies of As
     ╥        palindromize it horizontally
      ≤       get the other copy of the "A"s on top
       .»I:   push floor(input/2)+1 twice
           ž  and at those coordinates in the palindromized diagonals place in the row of As
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 66 bytes

```ruby
->n{(0...n).map{|i|(s=(i==n/2??A:?\s)*2*i+?A)[0]=?A;?\s*(n+~i)+s}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNAT08vT1MvN7GguiazRqPYViPT1jZP38je3tHKPqZYU8tIK1Pb3lEz2iDW1t7RGiikpZGnXZepqV1cW/tfxc7GJi3aJFbLPibvPwA)

Returns as array of lines

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>23</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
=þ`o\L‘HĊƲ¦UŒBị⁾A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//PcO@YG9cTOKAmEjEisaywqZVxZJC4buL4oG@QSD/w4dZ//80MA)

`` =þ` `` creates an identity matrix of size `n`.

`L‘HĊƲ` finds the row index of the horizontal bar with `¦` picking that row out and applying `o\` to it which creates the bar.

`U` reverses each row so we don't have an upside down "A" and `ŒB` (palindromize; vectorizes) makes the second half of the "A".

`ị⁾A` (with a space that is getting trimmed in the formatting) replaces `0`s with spaces and `1`s with `A`s.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 124 bytes

A fairly naive solution, gave it a shot to practice js skills.

`for(i=-1,p=" ".repeat(n-1)+"A ";++i<n;console.log(i-~~(n/2)?p:p.slice(0,i)+"A".repeat(n)),p=p.slice(1,n)+" "+p.slice(n-1)){}`

Unpacked

```
for(
 //create the first line
 i=-1, p=" ".repeat(n-1)+"A "; 
 ++i<n;
 console.log( 
 //if we are not at the bar
      i-~~(n/2)?
 //otherwise, use the modified previous line
      p
 //slice the start of the previous line and add As
      :p.slice(0,i)+"A".repeat(n)), 
 //add a space in between the previous line and remove padding on each side
 p=p.slice(1,n)+" "+p.slice(n-1)){}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 73 bytes

```ruby
->n{(0...n).map{|i|(?A.ljust(i*2,i==n/2??A:' ')+(i>0??A:'')).center n*2}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcfdCkAwFADgV9ndfnBo5UZty3PgAlFHnDRzITz7lO/u8@dwxdnEzNItCgAgCVu/3w8@wtWwLucRBCqdojGUa@fqijMuE4G2@MOlhHGiMHlGSr9v3D1SYHNTdsq1FD8)

Answer (score 1):

## [T-SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/sql-server), <s>182</s> 177 bytes

```
DECLARE @n INT=5DECLARE @ INT=0a:DECLARE @s VARCHAR(9)=STR(POWER(10,@),@n)PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(@s+REVERSE(LEFT(@s,@n-1)),'1','A'),'0',IIF(@=@n/2,'A',' '))SET @+=1IF @<@n GOTO a
```

First version (with 182 bytes):

```
DECLARE @n INT=5DECLARE @ INT=0WHILE @<@n BEGIN DECLARE @s VARCHAR(9)=STR(POWER(10,@),@n)PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(@s+REVERSE(LEFT(@s,@n-1)),'1','A'),'0',IIF(@=@n/2,'A',' '))SET @+=1 END
```

The version above works up to @n=9.

Here is another version, which works up to @n=23, but has 2 extra bytes:

```
DECLARE @n INT=5DECLARE @ INT=0WHILE @<@n BEGIN DECLARE @s VARCHAR(23)=STR(POWER(10.,@),@n)PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(@s+REVERSE(LEFT(@s,@n-1)),'1','A'),'0',IIF(@=@n/2,'A',' '))SET @+=1 END
```

Ungolfed:

```
DECLARE @n INT=5

DECLARE @i INT=0
WHILE @i<@n BEGIN
    DECLARE @s VARCHAR(9)=STR(POWER(10,@i),@n)
    PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(@s+REVERSE(LEFT(@s,@n-1)),'1','A'),'0',IIF(@i=@n/2,'A',' '))
    SET @i+=1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>98</s> <s>97</s> 95 bytes and 109 bytes

Two very different approaches. First (95 bytes):

```hs
c!n=([1..n]>>c)++"A"
f n=unlines[" "!(n-x)++drop 3([" "!(abs$n`div`2-x+1)!!0]!(2*x))|x<-[1..n]]
```

and second (109 bytes):

```hs
m True='A'
m _=' '
g n=unlines[[m(abs(n-j)==l||l==q&&elem j[q+1..q+n])|j<-[1..2*n]]|l<-[0..n-1],q<-[n`div`2]]
```

<s>[Try them here!](http://rextester.com/PDHKH9517)</s>; <s>[Try modified version here!](http://rextester.com/TBXH98462)</s>

[Try third version here!](http://rextester.com/SLVQ22299)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can save a byte on your first approach by [defining `l` as infix operator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19259/56433).

Comment: `m True='A'` an be shortened to `m b|b='A'`.

Comment: It turned out that even two bytes could be saved. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes or 65 bytes

List of strings is acceptable result, as @Budd stated in comments.

```
lambda n:['%*sA\n'%(n+i,('A'+i*2*' A'[i==n/2])[:-1])for i in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc29DsIgEADgWZ/iluY4ipoyOJAwsPcNKAPGvzN6NNjFp6edXb/lm3/Ls4hto5/aO38u1wziInb6GybBTknPRmHAnrXVCAEjey8nmyi6w5DoXiowsEDN8rgpodT@aDBncvvdXFkWQDy@CosaFRMZwO1oKw)

---

Seemingly cheaty solution, using `\b`. It looks funky in TIO, in console it does the job.

```
lambda n:['%*s\bA\n'%(n+i,'A'+i*2*' A'[i==n/2])for i in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcy9DsIgFAbQWZ/iLs0FSjQyODRhYO8blA40/l1TPxrs0qenzq5nOMu2vjJc7X2sc/pMt0ToBm7MN04hghuFViwHbsU4wxR4EO9xdqN@5EJCAioJz7uCHusfXexVd8fDUgQrMZ/eWaB6JVpb4l9edw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>93</strike>, 88 bytes

```python
lambda n:'\n'.join(f"{'A'+(x>0)*('A '[x!=n//2]*(x*2-1)+'A'):^{n*2-1}}"for x in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvBCoJAFADP9RUvQd5b3TK1LoKB36EGG7pl1FsxD7uI3256nGGmd@PLcLrovFo@6vtoFHCGFePpbTom7U1YYEj2dhYBYQFY2kPOUZTUAdkgOcYiXAOR3SfeaJ49bQaw0DEMip8tsRDLptymylhCIiGVcJFwrbP9rh86Hgn9pmL/hz45qcmJ9fkD)

-3 by @ovs using f-string

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 57 bytes

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
say$"x-$_.uc(A x($n+$_&-2?1:$n*2)|$"x2x$n++.A)for 1-$_..0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFqUJXJV6vNFnDUaFCQyVPWyVeTdfI3tBKJU/LSLMGKG1UARTV1nPUTMsvUjAEKdYz@P/f8l9@QUlmfl7xf928/7q@pnqGBnoGAA)