# Output a binary path from a number

Tags: code-golf, number

For an integer `n` that satisfies `n > 0`, write its value as a right-descending path based on its binary representation.

## Rules

- The first (most significant) set bit is always in the top-left corner.
- When the next bit is set (a `1`), draw a character ("filled") on the next line in the same column as the previous character drawn. Try to use spaces ("empty") to fill, but any character will do as long as it's always the same.
- When the next bit is unset (a `0`), draw a character ("filled") on the same line immediately to the the right of the previous character drawn.
- Your code must support numbers with at least 20 significant bits.
- Write a full program, a function, a lambda, etc. but no snippet.
- No leading spaces (or "empty" char) / lines allowed
- Any number of trailing spaces (or "empty" char) / lines allowed
- Any kind of 1D input is accepted: number, string, array of booleans, etc. Keep the order of bits untouched though.
- Any kind of visual 2D output is accepted: on stdout, a string (with any two distinct values representing "filled" and "empty"), you can even output a matrix if you want. A list of numbers seems hard to reconcile with the "no heading spaces" rule, but I'm open to it if you find a way to use it. Note: if you chose to print or return a string, the characters used must be ASCII characters in the codepoints range [32-126].
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/16236) are banned.
- This is codegolf so the shortest code wins.

## Examples

Input: 1

```
*
```

Input: 2

```
**
```

Input: 3

```
*
*
```

Input: 4

```
***
```

Input: 5

```
**
 *
```

Input: 6

```
*
**
```

Input: 7

```
*
*
*
```

Input: 25

```
*
***
  *
```

Input: 699050

```
**
 **
  **
   **
    **
     **
      **
       **
        **
         **
```

Input: 1047552

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
***********
```

Input: 525311

```
**********
         *
         *
         *
         *
         *
         *
         *
         *
         *
         *
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16132/16236)

Comment: Does _"allowed input array of booleans"_ mean that taking the input in the form of the number's binary representation as an array is allowed?

Comment: @Nit Any kind of 1D input. So if the number is 5, you may have an input array similar to `[1,0,1]`, yes.

Comment: So how free is that format really ? I'd like to take a number as the binary digits with the first 1 moved to the end, so since `9` is `1001` I'd like my input to be `0011`. Is that OK?

Comment: Having the first bit being `1` first is part of the challenge, and (re-)moving that bit would be trivializing the challenge so I'm afraid I'll have to say you no, @TonHospel . You can remove it from your input in the program, though.

Comment: Would graphical output be acceptable?

Comment: @12Me21 yes, as long as it's 2D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
¬œṗ+\Ṭz0
```

A monadic link accepting a number as a list of ones and zeros (e.g. `13` is `[1,1,0,1]`) returning a list of lists of ones and zeros where the first list is the first row.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QmqOTH@6crh3zcOeaKoP///9HG@ooAJEBEoJwDWMB)** or see a formatted [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QmqOTH@6crh3zcOeaKoP/R/c4HW5XedS0JhKIgSgLRDXuszq0LQtIHdp2aNv//4Y6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuY6RkDK0tLA1EDH0MDE3NTUSMfUyNTY0BAA)

#### How?

```
¬œṗ+\Ṭz0 - Link: list L           e.g. [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1] (i.e. 205)
¬        - logical NOT L               [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0]
    \    - cumulative reduce L by:
   +     -   addition                  [1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5]
 œṗ      - partition @ truthy indices  [[1,2],[2],[2,3,4],[4,5]]
     Ṭ   - un-truth (vectorises)       [[1,1],[0,1],[0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1]]
      z0 - transpose with filler 0     [[1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1]]
         -                        i.e.  1000
                                        1110
                                        0010
                                        0011
                                        0001
```

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
J_iB^YsJ+'o-'&XG
```

Produces graphical output as a path starting at coordinates (0,0). Try it at [**MATL Online!**](https://matl.io/?code=J_iB%5EYsJ%2B%27o-%27%26XG&inputs=699050&version=20.8.1) Or see some offline examples below:

- Input `7`:

[image]

Output:

[image]

- Input `699050`:

[image]

Output:

[image]

If you prefer, you can see the path as complex coordinates for **9 bytes**:

```
J_iB^YsJ+
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3ys@0ykusthL@/9/cwA)

###Explanation

```
J_      % Push -1j (minus imaginary unit)
i       % Push input number
B       % Convert to binary. Gives an array of 0 and 1 digits
^       % Power, element-wise. A 0 digit gives 1, a 1 digit gives -1j
Ys      % Cumulative sum. Produces the path in the complex plane
J+      % Add 1j, element-wise. This makes the complex path start at 0
'o-'    % Push this string, which defines plot makers
&XG     % Plot
```

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
YsG~YsQ1Z?
```

Inputs an array of binary digits. Outputs a matrix.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P7LYvS6yONAwyv7//2hDBUMFAyA0jAUA)

#### Explanation

```
Ys    % Implicit input: array of binary digits. Cumulative sum. This gives the
      % row coordinates
G     % Push input again
~     % Negate: change 0 to 1 and 1 to 0
Ys    % Cumulative sum
Q     % Add 1. This gives the column coordinates
1Z?   % Matrix containing 1 at those row and column coordinates and 0 otherwise.
      % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>100</s> <s>99</s> <s>81</s> <s>78</s> <s>73</s> 66 bytes

```python
a='';x=0
for c in input():a+=('\n'+' '*x)*c+'*';x+=1-c
print a[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9FWXd26wtaAKy2/SCFZITMPiApKSzQ0rRK1bTXUY/LUtdUV1LUqNLWStdW1gEq1bQ11k7kKijLzShQSow2tYv//jzbUUTDQUSCHjAUA)

Recursive version:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>71</s> <s>69</s> 67 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x=0:n and('\n'[:x]+' '*x)*n[0]+'*'+f(n[1:],x+1-n[0])or''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VclBCoMwEEDRvaeY3WQ0haitxYAnSV0kaKigo6QppKdP7bK7z/vHJz53bnL2w2o3N1lgmQalGSxPAh@MRqexQsAyUclGnV1i5QWbWo8yVfXlh7QHxDzNHpxg0gWEOb4Dw7q8otjsIRaO0i18TtPokagojnAaeOFE1/fqpv6tvd67lih/AQ)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```
γ€gć¸s>«1IÔ·ÌΛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OZHTWvSj7Qf2lFsd2i1oefhKYe2H@45N/v//2hDHQUgMgAjw1gA)

**Explanation**

```
γ€g             # Push the input as the array as chuncks of consecutive elements, map with length
   ć¸s>«        # Increment each value except the first one
        1I      # Push 1 and the input       
          Ô     # Push connected uniquified input (first elements of each chunck of consecutive elements in the input)
           ·Ì   # Map each with 2 * a + 2
             Λ  # Draw canvas :-)
```

- 3 bytes thanks to @Emigna

[05AB1E canvas's explanation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160031/76822)

Comment: `γ€gć¸s>«1IÔ·ÌΛ` should save 4 bytes.

Comment: @Emigna Brilliant, thanks ! Totally forgot that there was an a+2 builtin o:

Comment: I realize these weren't possible yet when you posted your answer, but you can save 3 bytes now in the new 05AB1E version by changing `γ€g` to `Åγ`; `ć¸s>«` to `>ć<š` and `1I` to `$`: [Try it online: `Åγ>ć<š$Ô·ÌΛ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOu5zXZH2m2OLlQ5POXQ9sM952b//x9tqKMARAZgZBgLAA).

Answer (score 6):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>155</s> <s>123</s> <s>120</s> <s>113</s> 101 bytes

Saved 32 bytes due to input being able to be received as an array of bits.
Saved 7 bytes thanks to @auhmaan.
Saved 10 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen.

```cs
n=>{var m="";for(int i=0,c=1;i<n.Length;)m+=n[i++]<1?c++%1+"":(i>1?"\n":"")+"0".PadLeft(c);return m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBNawIxEIbP7q8YAoWE2GW30ILGrJRCTxYECx62HmLMbgNuQidZQcTfvo0ftMcZnvdjRodH7dEMfbCuhdUxRNPlC@t@RJbpvQoBluhbVB2cslGIKloNB2938KGsoyFiktUbUNgGlpDs7vDeOz2zLtabMdygChqQg5PV6aAQOkmIaDzSxICVxVjLUtiZyxfGtfFbsI5LV1vON7Nyrjl/KDkhU2qrck6@HJkSwjgpSL5Uu4VpItVMoIk9OujEeUjdL76u77YGQcLLZFI8FyK7FoKtjSEt703fvDsYjPmnX1170ptqDE8sX5m90clcVkmZsjAYqv9JxlgaXhHVkTLxd3tyDH5v8jXaaNIrDW3oJZNdmNE5Ow@/)

Comment: Can't you change the `+new string(' ',c)+"*"` to `+"*".PadLeft(c)` ( saves 7 bytes ) ?

Comment: @auhmaan You're right, thanks!

Comment: -4 bytes by printing `0` instead of `*`: `if(n[i++]<1){m+="*";c++;}` to `if(n[i++]<1)m+=c++%1;` and `"*".PadLeft(c);` to `"0".PadLeft(c);`

Comment: Correction, it's actually -12 bytes because `m+=` can now be a ternary-if: `m+=n[i++]<1?c++%1+"":(i>1?"\n":"")+"0".PadLeft(c);`

Comment: @Oliver Umm.. now `c` isn't used at all anymore, and so it also doesn't pad.. (Try any other number like 699050 in your linked TIO.)

Comment: Then again, the current answer also fails for `699050`..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, using `0`'s and the use of the ternary operator is really smart! I also fixed the case for `699060`, by simply setting `c` to one the beginning, I kinda missed that while checking the test cases.

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>22</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ｆ⮌Ｓ¿Ｉι↑*←*
```

Only my second Charcoal answer thus far.

Takes the input as binary-String (i.e. `699050` as `10101010101010101010`).

-9 bytes thanks to *@Neil* suggesting to loop backwards.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98tv0gjKLUstag4VcMzr6C0JLikKDMvXUNTU5NLQcEzTcM5sbhEI1NTUyEAKF6iYRVaoKOkpaRpreCaU5wKE/RJTSuBCP//b2iACf/rluUAAA)

**Explanation:**

Read STDIN as string in reversed order:

```
Reverse(InputString())
⮌Ｓ
```

Loop over its binary digits as strings `ι`:

```
For(Reverse(InputString()))
Ｆ⮌Ｓ
```

If `ι` casted back to a number is 1, print the `*` upwards, else print the `*` towards the left.

```
If(Cast(i)) Print(:Up,"*"); Else Print(:Left,"*");
¿Ｉι↑*←*
```

Comment: This would be half as long if you printed the string in reverse, starting at the end and working up and left.

Comment: @Neil Ok, now it should be fixed. Thanks! -8 bytes

Comment: Save another byte by removing the `{}`s.

Comment: @Neil Ah, I had hoped the verbose converter would be smart enough to golf those kind of things itself. ;) Including `Assign(InputString(), a);` to `InputString(a);` or `Print(:Right, "*");` to `Print("*");`. Thanks! I still have a lot to learn, but it's an amazing language for sure!

Comment: `Print(:Right, "*")` isn't the same as `Print("*")` because the latter is affected by `PivotLeft()` and `PivotRight()`.

Comment: @Neil Ah of course. Ah well, I should just golf the verbose version as much as possible as well. Removing those brackets from the For-loop is part of the golfing process I guess, same as I golfed `Equals(i, "1")` to `Cast(i)` in my answer.

Comment: FYI operating on decimal input is still only 17 bytes: `ＮθＷθ«¿﹪θ²↑*←*≧÷²θ`.

Comment: Ah, that's a pretty cool method by taking as number and keeping it a number as long its not 0 yet. Still, even if taking the input as decimal would be mandatory, I could just change `InputString()` in my current answer to `Cast(Base(InputNumber(),2))` and it would still be only 13 bytes. :) Out of curiosity, why is the program flow output when using argument `-a` not the same as the verbose code with argument `-vl`? Is there a reason the current `-a` format was chosen? Or is there another argument-flag that's the inverse of `-vl` that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Oh, I forgot about `Base`... I don't know of an inverse to `-v`, I also use `-a` if I want to understand the succinct code.

Comment: `Base` only costs 1 byte as you don't need the `Cast` at all: `Ｆ⮌↨Ｎ²¿ι↑*←*`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sorry for the late reply, but to answer your questions: there is no reverse of `-v`, since Charcoal was designed as a golfing language, and I added verbose mode just to make it easier to type and understand. (I can add one if you want though). `-a` is short for `--ast`, I added it (format taken from PyTek btw) to help me understand the succinct code with as little effort as possible :P (and it _really_ helps when you've accidentally messed up argument order). Also, not that `-l` is a _separate_ option. (also just do `-h` for help on/descriptions of command-line args)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 65 bytes

```hs
f(a:b)|a="*":f b|(x:y)<-f b=('*':x):map(' ':)y
f[]=["*"]
f.tail
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0SpJsybRVklLySpNIalGo8KqUtNGF8i01VDXUreq0LTKTSzQUFdQt9Ks5EqLjrWNBiqN5Uq3TdMrSczM@Z@bmJlnW1BaElxSpFKal5OZl1qskh4dUlSaquOWmFOcqgNmIgiwYOx/AA)

Takes input as a list of booleans.

## Curry PAKCS, 70 bytes

```hs
u(a:b)=('*':a):map(' ':)b
f(a:b)|a="*":f b|1>0=u$f b
f[]=["*"]
f .tail
```

Port of the Haskell answer, but because `<-` doesn't work in Curry we need to make a helper function `u`. We also need to add a space between `f` and `.` so that Curry parses it as a compose rather than a dot.

This also works in MCC Curry, but doesn't work in Sloth Curry (which is the only one supported by TIO).

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>74</s> <s>70</s> <s>67</s> 62 bytes

```hs
tail.("\n"%)
s%(x:r)=([1..x]>>s)++'*':(s++[' '|x<1])%r
s%[]=""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY4xC8IwFIT3/opHoCQxGGzdiuniqlBwEdIM0WoNprE0VTr4243J8Ljv4Lh3D@2fN2vDxTjYgACpsoQuYlLSmU80JQXGQA6vLhmVZb1ow6yN5QS1DuU08zlZqokKIgvOF1XXnjKGV7ginjGJAX@XXaFoPsWkVAKhMGiTvgx6PAIZ3/Npng4OOBDGUieN2MdLKyik1m2pwu96t7r3YX3eN80f) Takes a list of zeros and ones as input and returns a newline separated string.

Inspired by [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161507/56433).

Comment: [A little friendly competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161594/56656).

Comment: @user56656 Your turn again :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
s=p='\n'
for x in input():s+=p*x+'*';p+=' '[x:]
print s[2:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcZBCoAgEEDRfaeY3ZS2UJeGJzG3kRsd1MBOP0lQ8Ph8utuZk2GujhzuCacjF@gQ00BXmxdbpSPRJQrcSDoE9N2GiUpMDao3NjB7vcKg3v6jPjo8)

Based off [TFeld's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161449/20260).

Answer (score 3):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 251 bytes

```
b2c*eykbi ki1y eyyye cyy ce  ey
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f9h/oRuhQ/zZzUBid52EHfah/l9rR/m9@8HCQDxsqQP86csBEpMNQLxkoG8JVogAshblwphQDiVSJxl2UBiIUhrU6ZCNtSorg/zZ8wGmZYJUmUIVQqXqVRIhXI7gXgyhD2joRIqgGI@iNO7KlUhGUSh6oDKVcLlQK4EMaYsUQATqUh6OuE2/AcRXECPN4KM4VKABYOCmaWlgakBkoChgYm5qakRF1gXAA)

This is definitly not a golfed solution, but there isn't a person alive that would consider Emoji-code a golfing language. However, in the process of subjecting myself to the horrors that are emoji-code's syntax in an effore to teach myself this monstrosity of a language, I've been pleasantly surprised by just how powerful and efficient it can be

**Explaination:**

```
       Define Class
     Define Method
b2    Convert Input integer to binary string
c*     asterisk string
e     Spacing string
y     output string
kb     translate to iteratable
i k     for-in loop to iterate over each digit 
i1     if digit is 1:
y e     don't print initial newline
y     print spaces + asterisks
y     reset output string
ye c     add correct number of spaces and one asterisk
     if digit is 0:
yy c     add an asterisk to the output string
e  e     add another space to the space string

y     print one last output string

     Start Program
  699050     Call Method
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

Same I/O format and same logic as the recursive version below.

```javascript
a=>a.map((n,i)=>n?i&&p+0:+(p+=' '),p=`
`).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY69DoIwFEZ3n@JOtA3Xhh8rUVOcXF0ckYSKoDVy2wD6@ggOX3Ly5QznZb5mqHvrxzW5ezO1ejI6N7IznnNCK3RORxsEPoz2IfehZsAEel2tKiFfzlJVTYciRkgQUoQNgkLYImTzs9BuF6kIIY42mVKzoxKVxnG5kq3rT6Z@cgKdQ@1ocO9Gvt2Ds4JBCDSPlVdauOWFlJLk6C5jb@nBE1H@A8@f7tb0QizurAox/QA)

Or **42 bytes** if [this format](https://tio.run/##HY6xDoIwFEV3v@JNtg3PhqKVoClOri6OSGJFQAy8NoD@PoLDTU5uznDe9muHom/8uCH3LKfKTNakVnbWc07YCJPSqVmvfRAeAu4DwwCYQG/uq7uYjplCiBC2CDsEjbBHiOdnoSQJdYigwl2s9ezoSG@Vyleycv3ZFi9OYFIoHA2uLWXras4yBgHQPJbfaOGKZ1JKkqO7jn1DNY9E/k@7fLpH2QuxuLMqxPQD) is acceptable.

---

## Recursive version, 56 bytes

Takes input as an array of integers (0 or 1). Uses `0` for filled and space for empty.

```javascript
f=([n,...a],p=`
`,x=0)=>1/n?(n?x+0:+(p+=' '))+f(a,p,p):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY4xb8IwEEZ3fsVtvpOvrh1wESDD1LVLxzQSJk0oCM5WSCv@feoMn/T06Q3vGv/iox0ueXyR9N1NUx@wFjbGxIZzOC6O/AyWwt69ygHl8NR2qzHroEAR6R4jZ860jdOudgwVw5JhxeAZ3hjW5Zlps7HeMji7WntfHF/5pXPNwvRpeI/tDwqEPbRJHunWmVs6o6oVaJAy1XzJzD3WpUrMmD7H4SJnrKgx95jx4/d@6gai2S0q0fQP)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (               // f = recursive function taking:
  [n, ...a],        //   n = current bit; a[] = remaining bits
  p = `\n`,         //   p = padding string, initialized to a linefeed
  x = 0             //   x = 0 on the 1st iteration / equal to p after that
) =>                //
  1 / n ?           // if n is defined:
    ( n ?           //   if n = 1:
        x + 0       //     append x + 0 --> either the integer 0 on the first iteration
                    //                      or the padding string followed by a '0'
      :             //   else:
        +(          //     append the integer 0 (whitespace coerced to a number)
          p += ' '  //     and append a space to the padding string
        )           //
    ) + f(a, p, p)  //   append the result of a recursive call with x = p
  :                 // else:
    a               //   append the empty array a[], forcing coercion to a string
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>100</s> 106 bytes

```java
b->{var s="";int i=0,j;for(var c:b){if(c)for(s+="\n",j=i;j-->0;)s+=0;else++i;s+=1;}return s.substring(1);}
```

Takes an array of booleans and returns a String (`0`s are empty, `1`s are filled). Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##lVLLboMwEDw7X2FxCRYBQVoapS6R2lsPPeWY5mCIQ0yJiWxDFUV8O10eeSin5rRivTM77EzGKuZmm5/mUMa5SHCSM63xFxMSn0ZISMPVliUcfwjJ1LHtoaVRQqb4wMzOjosi50yu1liW@5grQkeoHqGBTBtmoFSF2OA9UNo9FKaZSjXp2AbiuC8RbmJ3caqYwjqyLAoCsIj8SUa3hbLbdvIak5PY2glpO9qJrG9pTbJI0Mx1Fz4l0PIpzzV3HEHhI6C14qZUEmtPl7HuJNgBoXWDEMhFLU@3B7YHFMpbhGdQHYfAK1oeteF7ryiNdwCoyaXdi/W6C2xEKoy2BSFOq6Q9wD8h0/BxzMt87of@47jAf56F4fRxYDgNn4LgBte6q0TFDD/be83A@RZwzCEOt4G5WPwJqUq58kzRm9@/29cEoXtKAEn@e9k06My5TEEpWd@76HcuDthh7Gpo316JNUwOTMmOqXcDJuIowuNg3BIOoemnux@vmz8).

Thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%C3%A9goire) for helping me golf it a bit more and alerting me to the fact that my output format was not up to the spec.

Ungolfed version:

```java
b -> { // lambda taking an array of booleans as argument
    var s = ""; // the output String
    int i = 0,  // the number of "empty" characters to output
    j;          // iterator variable for outputting the "empty" characters
    for(var c : b) { // iterate over the boolean array (the binary digits)
        if(c) // if it's a '1'
            for(s += "\n", // output a newline
            j = i; j-- > 0;) s += 0; // output the "empty" characters
        else // if it's a '0'
            ++i; // move one to the right on the next line
        s += 1; // output the "filled" character
    }
    return s.substring(1); // output the constructed String, minus the leading newline
}
```

Comment: I golfed 5 bytes: `{if(c){s+="\n";for(j=i;j-->0;)s+=0;}else++i;s+=1;}`

Comment: Even further: `{if(c)for(s+="\n",j=i;j-->0;)s+=0;else++i;s+=1;}`

Comment: Though, you don't print on the first line but on the second one. From the challenge: "No leading spaces (or "empty" char) / lines allowed"

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks. I have edited.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 38

```bash
dc -e?2op|sed 's/\B1/^K^H*/g;s/[10]/*/g'
```

Here `^K` and `^H` are literal vertical-tab and backspace control characters.  These don't render well on browsers, so this script may be recreated as follows:

```bash
base64 -d <<< ZGMgLWU/Mm9wfHNlZCAncy9cQjEvCwgqL2c7cy9bMTBdLyovZyc= > binpath.sh
```

Run in a terminal.  Input is via STDIN.

This answer may stretch the specifications too far - there are in fact no leading characters on each line of output - all positioning is done with control characters.  If this is too much of a stretch, then the output may be piped to `|col -x|tac` for an extra 11 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 113 bytes

```
@set s=
:l
@shift
@if %1.==0. set s=%s%+&goto l
@echo %s%+
@if not %s%.==. set s=%s:+= %
@if %1.==1. goto l
```

Takes a list of bits as command-line arguments. Uses `+` instead of `*` because `*` has a special meaning inside `%s:...=...%` expansions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 83 bytes

```java
a->{int m[][]=new int[20][20],r=0,i=0;for(int b:a)m[r+=i<1?0:b][i++-r]=1;return m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBb4IwFMbv/BUvJktASgMoc4K47LJkh508Eg4FwdVBIW1xIYa/3RVUZrK47NA2fd/3fl9f9@RArP3280TLuuIS9uqOG0kLnDcslbRieBpoaUGEgHdCGRw1gLpJCpqCkESq41DRLZRK0zeSU7aLYiB8J4zBCvB64awok1GMhj2K15BDeCLW@qgKUPalkGVf0MuuHfcL8dBGNLSDvOJ670p8YpQRN0O6cp5tP4kjapoWj0Mn4JlsOIMy6E7BkDrEgMyEFBDC0UEumqE58tAjWiBXHcul7dnIsecLz3OR53ozx@kCbWhWgTAk9v3@mXId54pOKCO8Vew3JrNdxrGszuPrvR2Ba@D0g3ChG7gktZ5a69SaPxnK9sI5aXUjuMUpIM9EU0gFzDGp66LVzwmjb9MKmZW4aiSuVY4s2JD0lz5qlx/sU/xL0M88owxUibf139BcnzykE0Snjm3O3JEP0Gn3Wm7f0f3jrfe1vrvTutM3)

- Supports at most 20 bits.
- Input as `int[]`
- Output as `int[][]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```js
Ë?R+Tî +Q:°T©QÃ¬x
Ë?                 // Map over the input and if the current value is 1:
  R+               // Return a new line and
    Tî +           // a space repeated T (with initial value 0) times and
        Q          // a \".
         :         // If the current value is 0:
          °T       // Increment T
            ©Q     // and return \".
              Ã    // When all of that is done,
               ¬   // turn the array into a string
                x  // and trim it, removing the excess new line at the start.
```

Takes input as an array of bits, for example `[1,0,1]`, outputs `"` instead of `*`.
Shaved two bytes off thanks to [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//3C3fZB2yOF1CtqBVoc2hBxaGXi4@dCaiv//ow11DHUMgBBCAulYAA)

Comment: Nice one. You can replace `SpT` with `Tî` - `î` is similar to `p`, except it defaults to `" "`. Also, there's a shortcut for `q `: `¬`

Comment: @Oliver Thanks, I didn't know about `î`, certainly very handy. I often check for chances to use the shortcuts, but I still always miss some of them, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 126 bytes

```hs
(#)n=maximum.map(!!n)
f l|s<-scanl1(zipWith(+))$(\a->[1-a,a])<$>l=unlines[[last$' ':['#'|elem[x,y]s]|x<-[0..0#s]]|y<-[1..1#s]]
```

Input as a list of zeroes and ones. Transforms number into offset by `x↦[1-x,x]` and calculates the partial sums. Final output is done with two nested list comprehensions.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5BDoIwEADvvmINJLRBGmvixYCf8OCh9rBqCY3bldhi0PB3lNtM5jIdxocjmq@egRvfAtcaUucYjAVH0cFSxN2/gWEny9KE531BO4tMchNw9GEIKmAv1muWqxZoinUVb8ikxdf3Z586UUqZiwtWR6Mr3KCVdX6kZmDy7KIxhDHlBRQHU2TF5MgFM24@NtpprCuzVWqbRWunz1@0UnqROaDnRvRDOqWXatV/U8JuP/8A)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 65 or 46 bytes

Prompts for input of the integer

```
n←+/i←((1+⌊2⍟n)⍴2)⊤n←⎕⋄m←(n,n)⍴' '⋄m[⊂[2](+\i),[1.1]1++\~i]←'*'⋄m
```

or for numerical vector of the binary representation of the integer

```
m←(2⍴+/n←⎕)⍴' '⋄m[⊂[2](+\i),[1.1]1++\~i]←'*'⋄m
```

assuming I have read the comments to certain answers correctly and the latter input is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 59 bytes

```r
function(n,x=sum(n|1))matrix(1:x^2%in%cumsum((n-1)%%x+1),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3RCoIwGIXvfQoZDP4/J7WRBFKv4AtEgonWwP3C2mhRPfvSbqTuDt/hO8dG8kadNTX2ke7ztPfUOj0SED6Jr7mqAWAYL2oCmcSJSCxlPiWu3kk/K3FxRDjcvAF6SUTTOKsDyDLUimvirTdzB/SVwzQmAsYeln8oEJNqnpSb7a4oVHK32nXQAkuZYCuGR5k5@FEqRDwJKYaOLu761wjBGMYP)

Takes input as an array of bits.

Returns a boolean matrix of `TRUE` and `FALSE` representing a `*` and a , respectively.

Also has some stuff in the footer to print a matrix corresponding to the specs above, for ease of testing.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 23 bytes

```
p\*VtQINp+b*Zd.?=hZ)p\*
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=p%5C%2AVtQINp%2Bb%2AZd.%3F%3DhZ%29p%5C%2A&input=%5B1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
p\*VtQINp+b*Zd.?=hZ)p\*
p\*                       Print the leading *.
   VtQ                    For each bit (excluding the leading 1)...
      IN      .?   )      ... If the bit is set...
        p+b*Zd            ... Print a newline and a bunch of spaces...
                =hZ       ... Otherwise, increase the count of spaces...
                    p\*   ... Then print the next *.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>54</s> 36 bytes

```perl
s/./$&?"
".$"x$i.1:++$i&&1/ge;s/.//s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX09fRc1eiUtJT0WpQiVTz9BKW1slU03NUD891Rokq1/8/7@hoYGB4b/8gpLM/Lzi/7q@pnoGhgb/dQsA)

Cut it way down after I realized that the input could be a bit string.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>64</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```
INPUT N@L
GPSET X,Y
B=N<0X=X+B
Y=Y+(X>B)N=N<<1ON!N GOTO@L
```

The highest bit (sign bit) is checked, and if it's 1, the X position increases. If the sign bit is less than the X position (that is, the sign bit is 0 and X is not 0) the Y position increases.

The first movement will always be horizontally, so Y movement is blocked until after the first X movement. This ensures that the Y position doesn't increase during the leading 0 bits.

Then N is shifted left, and this repeats until N reaches 0.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```ruby
->n{s=""
n.to_s(2).gsub(/./){$&==?1?"
"+s+?*:(s+=" ";?*)}[1,n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBDoIwEADvvGKzGEOhFgpUAqb2IUCMGNFTNbYcTOnbK55mMpnPMn3DLMPhrJ2RiJFm9nUxSUnYwyxTkrOcuN1eSsUVRpiZTKVdYjKJgCeVEt9zqkcfNkBJoaJQUxAUjhSarfytbQtRUOBF3QixPaIUFecju19vT3CrXeG9WAMYO@u7Qcdu7u3oB40@/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 113 Bytes

```
def f(a):
 o='*';r=[o]
 for i in bin(a)[3:]:
  if'0'<i:r+=[' '*len(r[-1][1:])]
  r[-1]+=o
 print'\n'.join(r)
```

Not sure if this one counts (it outputs an array of each of the lines), but if so then I'll change my byte count to 103:

```
def f(a):
 o='*';r=[o]
 for i in bin(a)[3:]:
  if'0'<i:r+=[' '*len(r[-1][1:])]
  r[-1]+=o
 print r
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 85 bytes

```
Prompt L
1→X
1→Y
DelVar [A]
sum(LL
{Ans,1-Ans+dim(LL→dim([A]
1→[A](Y,X
For(I,2,dim(LL
Y+LL(I→Y
X+not(LL(I→X
1→[A](Y,X
End
[A]
```

Prompts for a boolean list, returns a matrix of 0 and 1.

Goes through the list, incrementing X if the next 'bit' is 0, changing Y otherwise, then adding a 1 to the matrix at that location, and returns the matrix at the end.

TI-Basic is a [tokenized lanugage](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens).

- 1 byte: `Prompt` , `L`*6, (newline)*12, `1`*5, `→`*7, `X`*5, `Y`*5, `sum(`, `L`*5, `{`, `Ans`*2, `,`*5, `-`, `+`*3, `dim(`*3, `(`*4, `For(`, `I`*3, `2`, `not(`, `End` = 73 bytes
- 2 bytes: `Delvar` , `[A]`*5 = 12 bytes
- Total: 85 bytes

---

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 56 bytes

```
Prompt L
1→X
1→Y
Output(Y,X,"*
For(I,2,dim(LL
Y+LL(I→Y
X+not(LL(I→X
Output(Y,X,"*
End
```

Same processs as above, but using graphical output (limited by screen size: 10 rows, 26 columns, so max 10 1s and 25 0s) as it goes, instead of adding to a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 30 bytes

```
JZFG.BQIsGIJk)p+*ZdN.?pN=hZ)=J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3yvKzV3PKdCz2N3TK1uzQFsrKsVPz77AzzYjStPW6/9/M0tLA1MDAA)

Uses `"` instead of `*`.

Python 3 translation:

```
Q=eval(input())
Z=0
J=Z
for G in "{0:b}".format(Q):
    if int(G):
        if J:
            print()
        print(Z*' '+'"',end='')
    else:
        print('"',end='')
        Z+=1
    J=Q
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86 .COM, 32 bytes

```
00h: 66 D1 E6 66 0F BD CE BF 24 AD 8E DF 41 66 0F A3 
10h: CE 19 DB 81 E3 9E 00 8D 79 02 C6 05 2A E2 EE C3 

fun:
shl esi, 1
bsr ecx, esi
mov di, $ad24
mov ds, di
inc cx
lab2:
bt esi, ecx
sbb bx,bx
and bx,158
lea di,[di+2+bx]
mov [di],byte '*'
lab1:loop lab2
ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

```apl
+⌿↑1↑¨⍨-+\,¨∘~⍨0,⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQZcjzra0/5rP@rZ/6htoiEQH1rxqHeFrnaMDpDRMaMOyDHQAar@D1T3Pwmow@hR19JHvYsPrTd81LWIiyuNK0nBkEtdHcwwgjGMYQwTGMMUxjCDMczhuhBylpYGpgYwnqGBibmpKdxMUyNTY0NDAA)