# ASCII art H trees

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, fractal

An [H tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_tree) is a fractal tree structure that starts with a line. In each iteration, T branches are added to all endpoints. In this challenge, you have to create an ASCII representation of *every second* H tree level.

The **first level** simply contains three hyphen-minus characters:

```
---
```

The next levels are constructed recursively:

- Create a 2x2 matrix of copies from the previous level, separated by three spaces or lines.
- Connect the centers of the copies with ASCII art lines in the form of an H. Use `-` for horizontal lines, `|` for vertical lines, and `+` whenever lines meet each other.

#### Second level

```
-+-   -+-
 |     |
 +-----+
 |     |
-+-   -+-
```

#### Third level

```
-+-   -+-   -+-   -+-
 |     |     |     |
 +--+--+     +--+--+
 |  |  |     |  |  |
-+- | -+-   -+- | -+-
    |           |
    +-----------+
    |           |
-+- | -+-   -+- | -+-
 |  |  |     |  |  |
 +--+--+     +--+--+
 |     |     |     |
-+-   -+-   -+-   -+-
```

### Rules

- Input is an integer representing the level of the ASCII art H tree as described above (*not* the actual H tree level), either zero- or one-indexed.
- Output is flexible. For example, you can print the result or return a newline-separated string, a list of strings for each line, or a 2D array of characters.
- You must use `-`, `|`, `+` and space characters.
- Trailing space and up to three trailing white-space lines are allowed.

This is code golf. The shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Related: [Create an “H” from smaller “H”s](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157664/create-an-h-from-smaller-hs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>20</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ø⁸«╵［↷Ｌ⇵；ｌ⇵└┌├-×╋‼│
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUY4JXUyMDc4JUFCJXUyNTc1JXVGRjNCJXUyMUI3JXVGRjJDJXUyMUY1JXVGRjFCJXVGRjRDJXUyMUY1JXUyNTE0JXUyNTBDJXUyNTFDLSVENyV1MjU0QiV1MjAzQyV1MjUwMg__,i=Mw__,v=8)

Explanation:

```
ø                    push an empty canvas
 ⁸«╵[              repeat input*2 + 1 times
     ↷               rotate clockwise
      L⇵             ceil(width/2)
        ;l⇵          ceil(height/2); leaves stack as [ ⌈½w⌉, canvas, ⌈½h⌉ ]
           └┌        reorder stack to [ canvas, ⌈½w⌉, ⌈½h⌉, ⌈½w⌉ ]
             ├       add 2 to the top ⌈w÷2⌉
              -×     "-" * (2 + ⌈w÷2⌉)
                ╋    in the canvas, at (⌈w÷2⌉; ⌈h÷2⌉) insert the dashes
                 ‼   normalize the canvas (the 0th iteration inserts at (0; 0) breaking things)
                  │  and palindromize horizontally
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
Ｐ-²ＦＮＦ²«⟲Ｔ²+×⁺²κＸ²ι←‖Ｏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBDoIwEEXXcIqG1UyEDe7wBCaCDeEClQyxsVBSpnVhPHstbFy@l//f@FRutMrE2HrDenV6YWiqUtR4ySfrBFyX1XPn5wc5QBSHq1F88qy3rJgGp5Yt2Rn2SyaPQnEq/jDomTaQxm9Ql@KFpZD2nWoJNOK@a20gaG408U49TYZGvgdyRq2Q1DfGc6yC@QE) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
Ｐ-²
```

Print the initial three `-`s, leaving the cursor in the middle.

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat for the number of times given.

```
Ｆ²«
```

Repeat twice for each `H`. Each loop creates a slightly bigger `H` from the previous loop, but we only want alternate `H`s.

```
⟲Ｔ²
```

Rotate the figure.

```
+×⁺²κＸ²ι←
```

Draw half of the next line.

```
‖Ｏ
```

Reflect to complete the step.

The result at each iteration is as follows:

```
---

|   |
+---+
|   |

-+-   -+-
 |     | 
 +-----+ 
 |     | 
-+-   -+-

|   |   |   |
+-+-+   +-+-+
| | |   | | |
  |       |  
  +-------+  
  |       |  
| | |   | | |
+-+-+   +-+-+
|   |   |   |

-+-   -+-   -+-   -+-
 |     |     |     | 
 +--+--+     +--+--+ 
 |  |  |     |  |  | 
-+- | -+-   -+- | -+-
    |           |    
    +-----------+    
    |           |    
-+- | -+-   -+- | -+-
 |  |  |     |  |  | 
 +--+--+     +--+--+ 
 |     |     |     | 
-+-   -+-   -+-   -+-
```

Comment: If you wonder how a 5-th level `H` looks like, a quick zoomed-out glance: https://i.imgur.com/EGapcrS.png

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 227 bytes

```python
L=len
def f(n):
 if n==1:return[['-']*3]
 m=[l+[' ']*3+l for l in f(n-1)];w=L(m[0]);y=L(m)/2;x=w/4-1;m=map(list,m+[' '*w,' '*x+'-'*(w-x-x)+' '*x,' '*w]+m)
 for i in range(y,L(m)-y):m[i][x]=m[i][w+~x]='|+'[m[i][x]>' ']
 return m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BbsMgEEX3nGJ2gIGkdrKyRU6QVbaIRaTaLRGMLeoKLFW9umucSN0Mw2fmff60zJ8jNut61b5H8t4PMDDkLQE3AGpdt7GfvyMaQxW11ckSCNp4YSiUq/AwjBE8OCx7qua2S/rKgnmzvFtKx49Nl3U6nlXdBR3uE/Pua5ZhR1RJlprFRq9YUlllLnZl15MVgZPdwhWLeMePni2yYNXC22CcNdnq/Uzid2vpj6DmpV/KJwk8E0BYCwcLp5aNPMnzlnKKDmdAAjddcpP/OLf2@Ubp4TE6ZJ6/ptc/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 118 bytes

```perl6
{map ->\y{map {' |-+'.comb[:2[map {$^b%%1*$b&&6>=$^a/($b+&-$b)%8>=2},$^x/¾,y/2,y,$x/3-$_]]},2..^$_*6},2..^$_*4}o*R**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcjPCoIwHMDxe08x5OfUuT@0RKJwD9FVnbhIKNKJXRzmq3XoxRZ46PLlw3e8Tc/c9w7hDhV@6dsRMVW5DUuE3iyN@NX2pjzJcnugTRjuCRiMc1WAbkUMJsUMTBIeVSFXCnoW3w91QlJHYRYHBk1dr1RyrqEh@V/ZasmFEOnPu1frUBdDkyjFH/Y@bImDaggS1NkJ6cz/AA)

0-indexed. Returns a 2D array of characters. The basic idea is that the expression

```perl6
b = y & -y   // Isolate lowest one bit
b <= x % (4*b) <= 3*b
```

generates the pattern

```perl6
--- --- --- ---
 -----   ----- 
--- --- --- ---
   ---------   
--- --- --- ---
 -----   ----- 
--- --- --- ---
```

#### Explanation

```perl6
{ ... }o*R**2  # Feed $_=2**$n into block
map ->\y{ ... },2..^$_*4  # Map y=2..2**n*4-1
map { ... },2..^$_*6      # Map $x=2..2**n*6-1
' |-+'.comb[:2[ ... ]]    # Choose char depending on base-2 number from two Bools
map { ... }  # Map coordinates to Bool
  # Horizontal lines
  ,$^x/¾  # Modulo 8*¾=6
  ,y/2    # Skip every second row
  # Vertical lines
  ,y      # Modulo 8
  ,$x/3   # Skip every third column
   -$_    # Empty middle column
# Map using expression
$^b%%1*$b&&  # Return 0 if $b is zero or has fractional part
6>=$^a/($b+&-$b)%8>=2  # Pattern with modulo 8
```